# Proxy contract DELEGATECALL to pass a DYNAMIC array to a function in the target contract

Tags: assembly, delegatecall, calldata, proxy-contracts

I'm trying to get a Proxy contract to correctly do a `delegatecall` to a function in another 'target' contract. The problem is, that I need to pass a *dynamic* array as the parameter to this function.

**Q: Is there a way to edit my Proxy contract's inline assembly code to correctly forward msg.data which contains a DYNAMIC array?** (I really need dynamic arrays to be passed to the function in the target contract).

My Proxy contract is similar to the OpenZeppelin implementation:

```
assembly {
      let ptr := mload(0x40)
      calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
      let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
      let size := returndatasize
      returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

      switch result
      case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
      default { return(ptr, size) }
    }
```

I give a simple example of the problem below:

This is the function which I wish to call through the Proxy contract:
`function myDynamicFunction(uint[2][] myArray)`

The delegatecall to this fails.

If I remove the 'dynamic' nature of the array, then the function is correctly executed. E.g.:
`function myDynamicFunction(uint[2][4] myArray)` (fixed array size of 4).

The delegatecall to this works.

Here's what I think the problem is:

Say I want to pass the following array (an array of 4 arrays of 2 elements) to myDynamicFunction:

```js
[["0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111",
"0x2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222"],
["0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
"0x4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444"],
["0x5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555",
"0x6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666"],
["0x7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777",
"0x8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888"]]
```

This is the **correct** msg.data of a dynamic array, which is passed into the Proxy:

```
0x
5a3d9eaf // (1) function signature
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 // (2) the 'start' of the dynamic array's data starts after 32 bytes
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 // (3) the dynamic array has 4 elements
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 // (4) element 1 [0]
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 // (5) element 1 [1]
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 // (6) element 2 [0]
4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444 // (7) element 2 [1]
5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 // (8) element 3 [0]
6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666 // (9) element 3 [1]
7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777 // (10) element 4 [0]
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 // (11) element 4 [1]
```

**However**, I believe the delegatecall reformats this message data into an incorrect format as follows (see the solidity code further below to see how I deduced this in remix):

```
0x
d608741f  // (1) incorrect function signature?
// then the array being passed as though it is of fixed size (rather than a dynamic encoding):
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 // (2) element 1 [0]
2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 // (3) element 1 [1]
3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 // (4) element 2 [0]
4444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444 // (5) element 2 [1]
5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555 // (6) element 3 [0]
6666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666 // (7) element 3 [1]
7777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777 // (8) element 4 [0]
8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888 // (9) element 4 [1]
```

I deduced the above by inspecting the transaction details of the below in remix (although note that the body of code in the below myDynamicFunction is used just as a 'rough' way to explore the msg.data of a delegatecall of a dynamic array - it is not the body of code I'm actually implementing):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract myContract {
   event Debug(bytes data);
   function myDynamicFunction(uint[2][] myArray) public returns (bytes) {       
       address(this).delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("myDynamicFunction(uint[2][])")), myArray);
       return msg.data;
   }
   function () {
       emit Debug(msg.data); //reading the event logs shows that the delegatecall is forwarding incorrectly encoded msg.data!
   }
}
```

Interestingly, if I edit the above Solidity delegatecall (with hardcoded function signature values) as follows, the delegatecall forwards the msg.data correctly - but I need to implement the delegatecall of any function signature (particularly ones which take a dynamic array of unknown size) in assembly:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract myContract {
    event Debug(bytes data);
    function myDynamicFunction(uint[2][] myArray) public returns (bytes) {       
        address(this).delegatecall(
            bytes4(sha3("myDynamicFunction(uint[2][])")),
            uint256(32), //the 'start position' of myArray in msg.data
            uint256(myArray.length), //the length of myArray
            myArray);
        return msg.data;
    }
    function () {
        emit Debug(msg.data); //reading the event logs shows that the delegatecall is now forwarding correctly encoded msg.data! But how to achieve this with assembly, without hard-coding the function signature?
    }
}
```

**How can I edit the assembly so that dynamic arrays are passed to the contract correctly, by the Proxy?**
Current assembly in the proxy:

```
assembly {
      let ptr := mload(0x40)
      calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize)
      let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, ptr, calldatasize, 0, 0)
      let size := returndatasize
      returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

      switch result
      case 0 { revert(ptr, size) }
      default { return(ptr, size) }
    }
```

Comment: I have a same issue.
Is there no solutions?